# How do I make checkbox check when I click on the label for repeated partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that I'm repeating n times in a view. Due to that, element ids are repeating and JQuery doesn't work right. So I have added html attribute for id and it works fine. But now I need to set the 'for' attribute in the label so that my check box gets checked when I click the label for that text box. This is the default functionality you get when you use CheckBoxFor Html Helper Method.

How do I set 'for' attribute for label in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your checkbox, add 'id' property

`@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PropertyName, new { id = "PropertyName_" + @Model.Id})`

In your label, add 'id' and 'for' attributes

`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertyName, "Some message (or it can be empty string)", new { id = "PropertyName_" + @Model.Id, @for="PropertyName_" + @Model.Id})`

And you should be able to click the text and checkbox should get checked. Just make sure the values of your ids in both elements and the @for attributes are all exactly the same.

Note: The id attribute in the LabelFor is optional for this functionality to work. I just set it as that is what Razor does by default if you don't pass HtmlAttributes.

Comment: Note: `LabelFor()` does not generate an `id` attribute for its element so that bit is not really necessay :). But the real problem you have here is that your generating duplicate `name` attributes which means this will not bind to your model when you post back (assuming your model is a collection of complex objects). Use a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` so your html is generated correctly with indexers (both `id` and `name` attributes)